# Como usar un while o un for loop durante la ejecución de un .exe en PowerShell

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Tengo un server de minecraft ejecutandose correctamente en una ventana de powershell necesito crear un while para que se envie un comando repetitivo a la aplicacion que esta siendo ejecutada, es decir, el server. Pero no logro poder usar los scripts de powershell. Solo reconoce los comandos del server.exe y por lo tanto me quedo sin poder ejecutar un while o un for loop

Comment: Tal vez algo de esto te ayude https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650210/13419694

Answer (score 0):

Si logras escribir tu comando repetitivo en la forma de una planilla con parámetros y si logras colocar los parámetros en un archivo .csv,  tal vez una función que desarollé te ayuda.  La función se llama Expand-Csv y realiza la expansion repetitiva de la planilla una vez por cada registro en el archivo de los datos.
Así, la repetición se realiza dentro de powershell,  y no dentro de la aplicación.

Aquí esta la función:

```
<#
.NOTES
    Script: Expand-Csv    Rev:  3.2
    Author: DGC           Date: 2-21-19
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates multiple expansions of a template,
    driven by data in a CSV file.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function is a table driven template tool. 

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.
#>
function Expand-csv {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $driver,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $template
    )
    Process {
       Import-Csv $driver | % {
           $_.psobject.properties | % {Set-variable -name $_.name -value $_.value}
           Get-Content $template | % {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 
       }
    }
}
```

Y aquí sigue un ejemplar donde la aplicación java es invocada en forma repetitiva, sacando los datos del id y user del archivo .csv y sutituyendo los parámetros en la planilla.

```
    Example 2:  Template
    --------------------
    
& java -jar --create -user $name -id $id -file D:/HR/$name-$id-form.pdf
   
    Example 2:  CSV File
    --------------------
    
NAME,ID
John,18
Dave,19
Carmen,20
Eric,21
Tom,22
Lisa,23
Kyle,24
   
    Example 2:  Driver
    ------------------
    

NAME   ID
----   --
John   18
Dave   19
Carmen 20
Eric   21
Tom    22
Lisa   23
Kyle   24


    
    Example 2:  Results
    -------------------
& java -jar --create -user John -id 18 -file D:/HR/John-18-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Dave -id 19 -file D:/HR/Dave-19-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Carmen -id 20 -file D:/HR/Carmen-20-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Eric -id 21 -file D:/HR/Eric-21-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Tom -id 22 -file D:/HR/Tom-22-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Lisa -id 23 -file D:/HR/Lisa-23-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Kyle -id 24 -file D:/HR/Kyle-24-form.pdf
```

Los parámetros se nombran NAME, ID en el archivo de los datos y $name, $id en la planilla. En tu caso puedes nombrar los parámetros como quieras.